# ggplot2 - proportion of sums for bar graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to plot the proportion of the sum of variable-values rather than the proportion of the number of observations.

As for the latter, the proportion of the observations for a given categorization (e.g. cut) can be done like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=diamonds) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..count../sum(..count..)),position="dodge")
```

In order to bring in information from values of another variables such as "price", one can map it to "y" and use "identity" notion:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=price),stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

However I'd like to combine both plotting the proportion of the sum of values of a variable (e.g. the sum of prices)
So one somehow has to map the the variable of interest (e.g. price) to say y which however than blocks y for the proportion calculation and I haven't seen an obvious way to to this other than aggregate the data (which I'd like to avoid).
'

To make my intensions possibly clearer, the ideal solution would look maybe something like this:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds) +
 geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..sum(price)../sum(..sum(price)..)),position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(data.frame(diamonds))
df <- df[,.(value = sum(price)), by = cut]

windows()
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = cut, y = value/sum(value))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") 

** New Answer **

library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(data.frame(diamonds))

windows()
ggplot(data = df[,.(value = sum(price)), by = cut], aes(x = cut, y = value/sum(value))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Comment: Even though this solution works, I was ideally looking for a native ggplot2 solution (which might not exist). I'll wait a bit longer for possible other answers and will accept this a solution if not native solution crops up.

Comment: what is native ggplot2?

Comment: What I mean is to use not any prior data manipulation, that is using the data as it is letting ggplot doing the calculations internally in build functions etc.

Comment: Sebastian I have updated my answer, you can directly use the df without creating a different one

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with `dplyr`:

```
  diamonds %>%
  group_by(cut) %>%
    mutate(sum_price = sum(price)) %>%
    mutate(prop_sum = price/sum_price) %>%
    ggplot(aes(cut, prop_sum)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```